# Is there any way to change the object being referenced in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, reference

I have some code that uses ObjectSpace._id2ref to get an object's reference from its id. I was wondering if there was any way to either change what that reference pointed to or change every variable that references a certain object, so that all variables referencing that object would have a new value. The code might look like:

```
a = 5
b = a
def change_ref(id, "hello")
    do_stuff()
end

a # => "hello"
b # => "hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the [SimpleDelegator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/SimpleDelegator.html) class that comes with Ruby's standard library:

```
require 'delegate'

a = SimpleDelegator.new(5)
b = a
p a     # => 5
p b     # => 5

a.__setobj__('hello')
p a     # => "hello"
p b     # => "hello"
```

There is almost certainly a way to avoid needing to do that that leaves your code simpler and easier to understand.  I would search for that.

Comment: +1 "There is almost certainly a way to avoid needing to do that that leaves your code simpler and easier to understand." I whole-heartedly agree with that.